# How do I display an input message JOptionPane.showInputDialog("foo") inside the method 'start' that is implementing a JavaFX scene?

Tags: java, javafx, joptionpane

I'm currently implementing the "start" method of the FX library to display a scene.

`

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT); 
        stage.setTitle("Foo1"); 
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D(); ...
```

`

Now, I would like to be able to prompt the user to enter data of type double via a dialog box.

`x = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter data"));`

But when I run the program, the box is actually created, but is locked to the task bar. However when I add the sentence to the main method, it does show up as it should. Could anyone help me please.

Comment: https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

Comment: Use the JavaFX API for such things (e.g. a [`TextInputDialog`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextInputDialog.html) or, more generally, a [`Dialog`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html)). As a basic rule of thumb, avoid mixing multiple UI frameworks together (i.e. don't use Swing in JavaFX unless you _have_ to).

Comment: One thing I discover is the JOptionpane does show on a Windows OS, and almost sure it would open on a Linux as well, but for some reason is not doing it in my MacOS

Comment: If @dehlen could help me out, I noticed he solved an issue similar to this before

Comment: As a possible solution to your problem, try putting the `showInputDialog` call on the _Event Dispatch Thread_ (Swing's UI thread) and, if necessary, publish the result back to the _JavaFX Application Thread_ (JavaFX's UI thread). Though again, I caution against mixing Swing with JavaFX. Use a `Dialog` or one of the available subclasses, such as `TextInputDialog`—they're (obviously) designed to work with JavaFX.

Comment: I don't know if I mentioned this @Slaw but I am fairly new in java, so if you could guide me a bit on how to do that, or a link that might explain how to work with Event Dispatch. I'll try to research on my own though and what I find I'll post.

Comment: Not to sound like a broken record, but try to implement what you need using JavaFX's dialog API. The link in [Sedrick's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59906901/how-do-i-display-an-input-message-joptionpane-showinputdialogfoo-inside-the?noredirect=1#comment105940064_59906901) provides good examples on how to use said API.